# Angular 6: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'afterClosed' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I am learning a MEAN stack app with angular 6. Here I want to refresh the component after adding a new client/car/driver/booking or updating a new client/car/driver/booking. But after adding a new value, the component showing all the values doesn't update or refresh(not able to see the current value at that time), but when i route between component and then go back to the same component it updates and shows all the values.

I am using **`afterClosed`** method of **`MATDialog`** to return all the clients value but there is an error 
**Error: Cannot read property 'afterClosed' of undefined**

How to resolve it?

Here is the `client ts` file.

```js
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog,MatDialogRef,MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { IClient} from './client';
import {Router,ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';

import {AddClientComponent} from './add-client/add-client.component';
import {EditClientComponent} from './edit-client/edit-client.component';

import {DialogService} from '../../dialog.service';
import {ClientService} from './client.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clients',
  templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients.component.css']
})
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentClient: IClient;
  clients: any;
  Client: any;

  addClientDialogRef: MatDialogRef < AddClientComponent > ;
  editClientDialogRef: MatDialogRef < EditClientComponent > ;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
    private dialogService: DialogService,
    private clientService: ClientService,
    private router: Router) {}

  openAddClientDialog() {
    this.dialogService.open(AddClientComponent, {
      width: '500px'
    });

  }

  openEditClientDialog(id) {
    this.dialogService.open(EditClientComponent, {
      width: '500px',
      data: {
        'id': id
      }
    })
  }

  closeAll() {
    this.addClientDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      this.getAllClients();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.closeAll();
    this.getAllClients();
  }

  getAllClients() {
    this.clientService.getClients().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.clients = res;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  deleteClient(id) {
    this.clientService.deleteClient(id)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.router.navigate(['./clients']);
        this.ngOnInit();
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }


}
```

Comment: Try setting the value dialog ref when you execute `open()` so that you can reference it later including executing `afterClosed()`. `this.addClientDialogRef = this.dialogService.open(AddClientComponent, { /* */ });`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thanx solved the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to reference events such as `afterClosed()` on the dialog references, you need to save the result of `open()` to the respective references:

```
// ...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clients',
  templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients.component.css']
})
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentClient: IClient;
  clients: any;
  Client: any;

  addClientDialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddClientComponent>;
  editClientDialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditClientComponent>;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
    private dialogService: DialogService,
    private clientService: ClientService,
    private router: Router) { }

  openAddClientDialog() {
    this.addClientDialogRef = this.dialogService.open(AddClientComponent, {
      width: '500px'
    });
  }

  openEditClientDialog(id) {
    this.editClientDialogRef = this.dialogService.open(EditClientComponent, {
      width: '500px',
      data: { 'id': id }
    })
  }

  closeAll() {
    this.addClientDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      this.getAllClients();
    });
  }

  // ...
}
```

Hopefully that helps!